# Call up other model's objects from array values rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms, collections

I have two models, `Clinician` and `Patient`.  A `clinician` `has_many: patients` and a `patient` `belongs_to :clinician`.

Besides the clinician that a patient `belongs_to` a patient also has a column called `shared_with`, which is a string holding an array of `clinician.id`.  This is done using `serialize :shared_with, Array`.

I would like to be able to select from a drop down of clinician's `full_name` for only clinicians who's `id` is included in the `shared_with` array.

```
<%= form_for [@clinician, @comment] do |form| %>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :clinician_id %>
  <%= form.collection_select :clinician_id, Clinician.all.order("last_name asc"), :id, :full_name, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :general_comment %>
  <%= form.text_area :general_comment, class: "form-control", rows: 5, placeholder: "Leave a comment" %>
</div>

<%= form.button 'Submit Comment', class: "btn btn-u btn-success" %>
```

Where I currently have `Clinician.all.order("last_name asc")` I would like to sort it so that I only have this shorter list.

I think it will be something like replacing what I have now with `@clinicians` and defining that as:

```
@patient = Patient.find_by(user_id: current_user.patient.id).shared_with
@clinicians = a list of clinicians where id: @patient.each
```

And using some method that is able to do this for me.

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which is a string holding an array of `clinician.id`

This terrible! Do not store the ids this way. You are trying to solve the wrong problem with your question.

Your array of shared_with ids should be a many to many relationship in the database with it's own table (Rails calls this `has_and_belongs_to_many`). A patient can be shared with many clinicians and a clinician may share many patients. Read the Rails guide on many to many relationships before going further: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference

You should end up being able to call `@patient.shared_clinicians` or similar to get a list of the clinicians for the dropdown.

Your models would look something like this:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :clinician
  has_and_belongs_to_many :shared_clinicians, join_table: 'shared_patients'
end

class Clinician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patients
  has_and_belongs_to_many :shared_patients, join_table: 'shared_patients'
end
```

Then a database table `shared_patients` with two columns: `clinician_id` and `patient_id`

Comment: Thanks @Matt, you're definitely right that using a table is a better way to manage these relationships.  Still learning Rails...  If I do as you recommend and create a `SharedPatient` table and the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships I still get an error.  I've seeded the database with a couple of examples but when I run `Patient.find_by(id: 1259).shared_patients.first` or `Patient.find_by(id: 1259).shared_clinicians.first` I get `NoMethodError: undefined method `shared_patients' for #<Patient:0x007f86e4d88c78>` or `uninitialized constant Patient::SharedClinician`. Advice?

Comment: For `SharedPatient` I have added `belongs_to :clinician` and `belongs_to :patient`

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method shared_patients' for #<Patient:0x007f86e4d88c78>` looks like the wrong method being called. Does `Patient.find_by(id: 1259).shared_clinicians` not work?

Comment: I get back `NameError: uninitialized constant Patient::SharedClinician`.  There is no table `SharedClinician`

Comment: Hmmm. It might be easier if you make a new question where you post all the code for your models, along with your db migration files. It's tricky to follow in the comments.

Comment: Please see my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462516/using-has-and-belongs-to-many-to-get-list-of-associated-objects-rails)