# Using has_and_belongs_to_many to get list of associated objects rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models, `Clinician` and `Patient`.  A `clinician` `has_many: patients` and a `patient` `belongs_to :clinician`.  A third model, `SharedPatient` is meant to store additional assosiactions between `patients` and `clinicians` as a `patient` can be shared by many other `clinicians` besides the one it `belongs_to`.  This is done using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.

See models:

```
class Clinician < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :patients
 has_and_belongs_to_many :shared_patients, join_table: 'shared_patients'
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :clinician
 has_and_belongs_to_many :shared_clinicians, join_table: 'shared_patients'
end

class SharedPatient < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :clinician
 belongs_to :patient
end
```

This is how my models are set out in the db:

```
Clinician:
 first_name: string
 last_name: string
 user_id: integer

Patient:
 clinician_id: integer
 first_name: string
 last_name: string
 user_id: integer

SharedPatient:
 clinician_id: integer
 patient_id: integer
```

Using these I would like to show the list of `clinicians` that a `patient` is shared with.

This is what I have in my controller now:

```
@patient = Patient.find_by(user_id: current_user.patient.id)
@clinicianslist = @patient.shared_clinicians
```

It am trying to show these in a view using:

```
<% @clinicianslist.each do |list| %>
 <p><%= link_to Clinician.find_by(id: list).full_name, clinician_path(list) %></p>
<% end %>
```

Using what I have now I am getting an error when trying to load the view:

> NameError in Patients#show
>
> uninitialized constant Patient::SharedClinician

I get the same error when running

> Patient.find_by(id: 1259).shared_clinicians

in console.

Any advice on solving this error or on structuring the models to get the associations I want would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `SharedPatient` model, so this should be deleted.

The error is because Rails cannot guess the class name from the association name or the table name. Try this:

```
class Clinician < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :patients
 has_and_belongs_to_many :shared_patients, join_table: 'shared_patients', class_name: 'Patient'
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :clinician
 has_and_belongs_to_many :shared_clinicians, join_table: 'shared_patients', class_name: 'Clinician'
end
```

This tells Rails which class to use. Currently, it is guessing `SharedClinician`, which is wrong.

Comment: Yes.. it is true.. I was wrong. I just completed my reading of the doco.. :) +1

Comment: to seed the join table and the associations would the best way be to do this: `p = Patient.create(clinician_id: clinician_a.id, first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", user_id: userp.id )
p.clinicians << Clinician.find_by_id("300")`

Comment: or with `shared_clinicians` instead of `clinicians`

Comment: @Matt, if I set it up as you describe and input `Patient.find_by(id: 1307).shared_clinicians` I get `Patient Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "patients".* FROM "patients"  WHERE "patients"."id" = 1307 LIMIT 1
  Clinician Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "clinicians".* FROM "clinicians" INNER JOIN "shared_patients" ON "clinicians"."id" = "shared_patients"."clinician_id" WHERE "shared_patients"."patient_id" = $1  [["patient_id", 1307]]
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "shared_patients" does not exist at character 52`

Comment: Have you made a db migration to create the table?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that in this case it does not really make that much sense with a join model. It would make sense if it for example was a `Appointment` object with its own data and logic.

Instead you should create a `patients_clinicians` join table, and define the relation as:

```
class Clinician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :patients
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clinicians
end
```

Convention over configuration...

Comment: You actually don't need to create a new join table, you could simply rename  `shared_patients`.

Comment: If I did this I wouldn't have a primary `clinician` attached to the `patient` through `Patient` having `clinician_id`.  I would need to have this relationship created separately as the patient is created - can I do `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on join tables?

Comment: Yes you can use nested attributes.

Comment: No, using HABM would not effect the "primary clinician" relation. I just omitted that part for brevity.

Comment: do you think this is a better option than a has_many :through association like `:has_many :clinicians, :through => :sharedrelationship`?

Comment: Its not better or worse, but sometimes it just does not make sense with join models.